Understanding error estimate for least squares fit.
I'm reading the following paper link.
In it, on page $7011$, the authors apply linear least squares to a system in the form
$$ {\bf A}x = b$$
Where $\bf A$ has $M$ rows and $N$ columns, they state an error estimate of the form
$$
err \approx \,\sqrt{\,{\frac{N}{M}}\,}\,
\left\vert\left\vert\,{\bf A}x - b\,\right\vert\right\vert
$$
when $M$ and $N$ are sufficiently large.

I don't understand where this comes from.
Is there any literature someone can point me to about this ?.

Best wishes.
